# WinUi 3 make enable of an control depends on value of 2 others

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have 2 static checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckOne" Content="I'm one" />
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckTwo" Content="I'm two" />
```

And collection of checkboxes binded to ObservableCollection:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CheckList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="CheckBox">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="False" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I need checkboxes in ItemsControl be enabled only if CheckOne is checked and CheckTwo is not checked. Is there any way to make this only using Xaml?

I tried to perform it using property in codebehind, something like:

```
public bool isCheckListEnabled { 
    get {
        if ((bool)this.CheckOne.IsChecked 
            && !(bool)this.CheckTwo.IsChecked)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
```

And bind it to IsEnabled property of checkboxes in the ItemsControl like:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="True" IsEnabled="{x:Bind isCheckListEnabled}" />
```

But I have warning that *"The property isCheckListEnabled was not found in type 'CheckBox'*.
I assume this is because of `<DataTemplate x:DataType="CheckBox">`, which means that `x:` is not Page anymore but CheckBox. How to bind now anything inside of DataTemplate to Page's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Page, this doesn't work with Window, you can add a `DependencyProperty` that represents the status of the CheckBoxes. This is a working example:

**MainPage.xaml**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App1;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControl),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControl
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControlProperty);
        set => SetValue(EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControlProperty, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new()
    {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
    };

    private void CheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControl = 
            this.CheckBox1.IsChecked is true &&
            this.CheckBox2.IsChecked is true;
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="ThisPage"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox
            x:Name="CheckBox1"
            Checked="CheckBox_CheckChanged"
            Unchecked="CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
        <CheckBox
            x:Name="CheckBox2"
            Checked="CheckBox_CheckChanged"
            Unchecked="CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <CheckBox
                        Content="{x:Bind}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ThisPage, Path=EnableCheckBoxesInItemsControl}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Note that I'm naming the `Page` **ThisPage** to do the binding from inside the `ItemTemplate`. This method should also work with `ListView` but not with `ItemsRepeater`.

Comment: Binding ElementName=ThisPage, yeah, that's what I needed. works perfectly, thanks! How about xaml only? is there any way to perform multi binding with conditions using only xaml? something like {Binding ElementName=CheckBox1, Path=IsChecked is false, ElementName=CheckBox2, Path=IsChecked is truel} ?

Comment: WPF does have MultiBinding but not UWP or WinUI 3.